# CSS properties and it's impact on performance?

Tags: css, performance, properties

we all know that CSS properties do have an impact on performance, but I can't really find an answer - do all properties have the same impact?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official statement anywhere that says "Not all properties have the same performance impact", but there is such a massive variety of properties with a plethora of effects that it's *inconceivable* that rendering a box shadow would have the same performance impact as downloading and drawing a background image, rendering a flex layout, or changing a font.

But if you want to test this yourself, you can create a thousand `div` elements, give them all a really large box shadow, and scroll the page. Then swap out the box shadow for a border, some padding, a background image, etc... and see if the page scrolls any better. You may need to turn off hardware acceleration in your favorite browser before you feel a significant difference. But it's certainly there.

Comment: There are actually plenty of "official" statements about properties and performance from browser developers. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/

Comment: @brianespinosa: Yeah, I think that'll be as official as it gets. I forgot that browser optimization guides exist. And a statement as simple as "This property is slower than the rest" is probably enough for the reader to understand that it'd render the statement "all properties have the same perf impact" false.

Answer (score 0):

There are DEFINITELY properties in CSS that impact browser performance more than others... `border-radius` and `box-shadow` are good examples of these.

In addition to properties, how you define values for properties can also impact performance. For instance, using `calc()` will start to impact performance if overused.

There are some selectors that are more expensive to use as well like the descendant selector.

I would recommend taking a read through [this article by John Otander](http://johnotander.com/css/2015/06/10/css-performance/). It's a little old but is still valid. And there are plenty of links at the bottom for further reading. But that will give you some bullet points regarding property performance.